# IPTables Rules flush Automatically on CentOs after few minutes

Tags: centos, iptables

I added some rules in the IPtables from command line. But after some time iptables flushes automatically.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save them. Run this after setting your rules :

```
service iptables save
```